# Python variable to float list

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using pandas to plot values on each bar. `dayspeed['Download']` will generate a Series like this:

```
0      3.83
1      3.19
2      3.83
3      3.82
4      3.84
5      3.82
6      3.87
7      3.86
8      3.85
9     20.33
10    19.15
11    14.57
12    13.06
13     3.82
14     3.11
15     3.83
Name: Download, dtype: float64
```

but when I apply it to a for loop, it shows integer type values.

```
labels = ["%d" % i for i in dayspeed['Download']]
```

labels

['3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3',
 '20',
 '19',
 '14',
 '13',
 '3',
 '3',
 '3']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the float flag `%f` instead of `%d` (digit/int):

```
labels = ["%f" % i for i in dayspeed['Download']]
```

to set float precision to 2:

```
labels = ["%.2f" % i for i in dayspeed['Download']]
```

example:

```
>>> l
[3.19, 2, 3.83, 3, 3.82, 4, 3.84]
>>> ["%f" % i for i in l]
['3.190000', '2.000000', '3.830000', '3.000000', '3.820000', '4.000000', '3.840000']
>>> ["%.2f" % i for i in l]
['3.19', '2.00', '3.83', '3.00', '3.82', '4.00', '3.84']
>>> ["%.4f" % i for i in l]
['3.1900', '2.0000', '3.8300', '3.0000', '3.8200', '4.0000', '3.8400']
```

Comment: Thanks! and how can it be rounded to 2?

Comment: @ColinZhong I've added an example with float precision

Comment: @ChrisMontanaro Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use vectorised operations on your dataframe since in general this will faster and more concise than a loop or list comprehension:

- Since your column has the datatype you can `np.float64` round by accessing the `round` method on your dataframe
- You can convert the datatype of a pandas series with the `astype` method.
- You can access the underlying `list` of values with `values.tolist()`:

For your case something like this: `df[c].round(2).astype(str).values.tolist()`